# What's the best way to make a CSV when we have millions of rows in the database - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, memory-leaks

I'm working on a project where I need to fetch millions of rows from the database and make a CSV file, but when I try to make a query to get all rows, the memory usage grows so fast and the application reach the 128M memory usage limit.
I tried to paginate the database rows using limit and offset, but that didn't help much. Is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: which API? `mysqli_`? `PDO`?

Comment: What did you try so far, like paste some code so we get a sense of what was attempted. It's easier to improve something than get what you're using/trying.

Comment: @Sirko I use mysqldump to generate Back ups, but it suddenly stoped working, I tried `system()` and `shell_exec()` but no luck.

Comment: @Max I paginated the result using limit and offset, and it worked.

Comment: @OllieJones I'm using Laravel, and I guess it uses PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `queue` approach for that kind of issue.

Say there are 100K rows in your database. Then you can create one job which writes 1K rows in a CSV file at a time and after appending those records it pushes the same job in queue. The same chain continues until you reach to your 100K rows. Of course when the counter reaches to 100K you need to kill the queue process.

As if you follow approach of PDO then you need to wait till the program finishes the execution. With my suggested approach you can call the queue once and it will do the job. You can do something like showing notification via email or something when your CSV is ready.

Have some research on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php).

Comment: I had an experience with queues and beanstalked, but that was only to handles mails. Using queues will be a very good thing to do. I'll take that into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: @Down voter, please clarify the reason.

Answer (score 2):

If the database is on the same physical box where you're running this export script, then:

```
SELECT <field list>
  FROM <table>
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/<filename>.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: I came across this solution in the internet but I don't know why I didn't test it. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never store all the data. Read the database line by line and output or write CSV after each.

```
$file = fopen('export.csv', 'w');
while($data = $query->fetch()) {
    fputscsv($file, $data);
}
fclose($file);
```

This way use very few memory.

Comment: He might end up in maximum execution time error. Consider he has millions of rows in database.

Comment: To avoid this, set_time_limit() can be used.

Comment: yes but end user has to wait till operation finishes. That does not sound feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mysqli_`, you can get into memory trouble with a large result set. That API's `query` call slurps the whole resultset into memory. As you've discovered, your resultset doesn't fit.

Instead, you should stream the rows of the result set from your database server to your client, and write them out one by one into your .csv file.  To do that, you will use

1. [real_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php) to issue the query.
2. [use_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) to initiate the retrieval of the mysqli_result set.
3. [fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) in a loop to retrieve the rows one by one.
4. [free](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php), when you're done fetching the rows, to release your mysqli_result object.

This problem also comes up with the other MySQL APIs. In the old and deprecated `mysql` API, use [mysql_unbuffered_query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php) instead of `mysql_query`.

In PDO, you should use an unbuffered query, by setting [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to false when creating the query object.

Notice that you may also have to set your [php time limit value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to a high value, because it may take a while to handle this megarow result set. You could also reset it in your fetch_row loop so it doesn't run out.

If you are using a shared hosting provider, you probably have to extract this data in chunks of 50,000 rows or so because hosting providers put hard limits on php script runtime.

Comment: Yup I used 50,000 rows at first but it would work some times and fail some times so I used 5,000 and it works fine now. Thanks.